# Change similar ng-repeat values from single source

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to change ng-repeat values separately, from shown single input text box. I'm trying to bind inputbox to label, but all values binding together.

How can I change only selected div values? I don't want to use ng-repeat to add values.

How can I do it without using ng-repeat in start add again you can use ng-repeat further functions. Form should be shown in certain position to change values in input box to label.
[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4fjW1TdVAmnqql2x3VjO?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

     $scope.items = [];
        $scope.add_New = function (index) {
        var itemhtml = '<div ng-click="select()" class="content">//click here first// <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{$index + 1}}. {{item.name}}</div></div>';
        var item = $compile(itemhtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(item);
          };
        $scope.add = function () {
          $scope.items.push({ 
            name: "hi"
          });
        };
        $scope.select = function(){
          $scope.showItem = true;
        }
});
```

```css
.add{
  position: absolute; height: auto; width: 200px; left: 0; right: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
.show{
  position: absolute; width: auto; left: 200px; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    border:1px solid red;
float:right;
}
.content{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
          <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <div class="add"><button ng-click="add_New($index)">add Again</button>
    <div id="drop">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="showItem" class="show">
          <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            {{$index + 1}}.<input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
            </div>
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>

          </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In my experience working with data and template is better than adding markup by hand. 
I don't get what's your goal btw.

Comment: @steo Actually what my requirement is ? i have to add name, email and mobile no and etc fields from left side if user want to add name or email in form it will be shown in main page dynamically if user click on that field, settings page will be opened on right side,from where i have to change each text values,, if i used ng-repeat i cannot able to see saved data in form, thats why i am using append to add values